# Strange router behaviour

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my Angular2 application I have a routing module like the following:

```
RouterModule.forChild([{
            path: '',
            component: HomeComponent,
            children: [
                { path: '', redirectTo: 'explorer/0' },
                { path: 'explorer', redirectTo: 'explorer/0' },
                { 
                    path: 'explorer/:id', 
                    component: EntitiesExplorerComponent,
                    children: [
                         { path: 'details', component: EntityDetailsComponent }
                    ]
                },
            ]
        },
```

As you can see the `explorer` path has a child.

The strange thing is that if I navigate to `/explorer/1` I get an error.
But if I navigate to `/explorer/1/details` everything works well.

I would like to present an explorer when I go to `/explorer/ID` and the details of an entity when I go to `/explorer/ID/details`.

This is the error: (it seems like it does not recognize `/explorer/ID`)

```
error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined
    at getChildConfig (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:61682:35)
    at Recognizer.processSegmentAgainstRoute (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:61648:27)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your router configuration should look more like this:

```
RouterModule.forChild([{
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'explorer' },            
        { 
            path: 'explorer',                
            component: AnotherComponentWithARouterOutlet,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    redirectTo: '0',
                },
                {
                    path: ':id',
                    component: EntitiesExplorerComponent,
                    children: [
                        { path: '', redirectTo: 'details' },
                        { path: 'details', component: EntityDetailsComponent }
                    ],
                },
            ]                
        },
    ]
},
```

If you now navigate to the URL `/explorer` the router should automatically redirect to the `/explorer/0`-route.

You have to create another component for the `explorer`-route. This component should contain a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in its template to load the children. The children are the `ids`. If there is no id given in the route the router redirects to `0`.

But the `:id` route has a `EntitiesExplorerComponent` with a `router-outlet`. The router wants to know what he has to load into this outlet. So you need to define an empty route for the children of `:id`. In my example above I just redirected to the `details`. If you don't want this, you should create another component for this `''`-empty route. This component may have a button like: `Click here to go to the details` or something like this.

Comment: Thank you Philipp.
In my use-case EntityDetailsComponent should be above the EntitiesExplorerComponent. So I need to display them at the same time.
This is why EntityDetailsComponent is a child of EntityDetailsComponent.*

I noticed that If I put a FakeComponent as child of EntitiesExplorerComponent: { path: '', component: Fake } it works.. but maybe there is a cleaner solution